# Saving python and other programs on D:\ for space reasons

Tags: hard-drive, windows-explorer

I have a new computer with a 235GB `C:` partition and 1TB `D:` partition, however there is not enough space on `C:` for all my documents, so I've put them on `D:` *(comes empty with no `Documents`, `Pictures`, `Desktop`, etc.)*.

I need to reinstall python, julia, java, etc., which by default install to `%LocalAppData%\Programs`:

- If my python project folders are saved on `D:`, but I install python, anaconda, jupyter, etc. on `C:`, will I have issues running my python files?
- Should I install python, anaconda, jupyter, etc. on `D:`, and since there is no ready-made `Programs` folder, should I make one?

Comment: **(1)** Move all your user data folders to `D:`, leaving programs on `C:`: Go to `%UserProfile%` → right-click each user data folder _(`Contacts`, `Documents`, `Downloads`, etc)_ → Properties → Location tab → Enter new path _(i.e. `D:\<username>\Contacts`, etc, but don't move them to the root of `D:` since it makes managing permissions easier when they're in a subdirectory within the root of `D:`)_  → OK **(2)** Leave programs on `C:`, else it makes it more of a headache when you take a backup image, since restoring a backup of `C:` would then not restore all programs

Comment: @JW0914 Will this create a problem for running code saved in file in D with programs (like IDE or python itself saved in C?)

Comment: No - when moving them via the Location tab, they retain all links and variables _(i.e. `%UserProfile%\Documents` will still point to the moved `Documents` folder)_

Answer (score 0):

You can safely move installations using Windows 10 Settings app. Open Settings > Apps and features, scroll down to your app and click Move. But you can't move all apps using this. You can use [EaseUS ToDo PCTrans](https://down.easeus.com/product/pctrans_trial) for this.

Comment: This does not answer my question...